# Защищенное подключение к сайту

Tags: laravel

Скрипт написан с помощью laravel 5.4
Как поменять подключение изображениий по протоколу http на протокол https ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Откуда система получает адреса? Тут три варианта:

1. База данных.
2. API
3. В самом коде

Если данные находятся в базе данных и если адрес такого типа: **http://site.com/image.png**, то писать SQL запрос, который перезапишет все http на https

Если данные в базе такого типа: /image.png, то в коде у вас отдельно берет домен сайта, то есть http://site.com . /image.png. В таком случае можно только поменять главный домен.
Если это API - обратиться к серверу.
Если это код - в ручную.

И покажите пожалуйста ваш код.